# How to Repair Grub while dual booting ( win7 / ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, dual-boot, prompt

I've installed windows 7 and then Ubuntu 11.10, and then set up everything on easyBCD.

When I select Ubuntu on the boot menu, I end-up in grub prompt (like "grub>" in a black screen) instead of loading Ubuntu directly.

I have to run:

```
grub>  root (dh0,4)
grub>  kernel /vmlinuzblahblah root=/dev/sda6
grub>  boot
```

Every time to boot Ubuntu(where vmlinuz is a long filename I always tab).

How could I skip this process?

Comment: Try reinstalling grub from Synaptic or do " sudo update-grub" from Ubuntu installed system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "Fix-Grub-routine" is as follows:

1. Boot from an Ubuntu LiveCD (USB key usually)
2. Mount the `/root` and `/boot` partition of my original install in the live environment. Lets say my root is mounted in `/tmp/myRoot/` and boot in `/tmp/myBoot/`
3. Mount/bind a few important directories
   `sudo mount --bind /dev /tmp/myRoot/dev

   sudo mount --bind /proc /tmp/myRoot/proc

   sudo mount --bind /sys /tmp/myRoot/sys

   sudo mount --bind /tmp/myBoot /tmp/myRoot/boot`
4. Chroot into my original installation
   `sudo chroot /tmp/myRoot/`
5. Now I'd usually do `update-grub` but since you messed up your bootsystem using some weird third-party application, I think it might be better to re-install grub using `grub-install /dev/sda` *.
6. When done, `exit` the chroot and reboot the system (without your live-media)

> *Note:* Replace `/dev/sda` with the drive you want grub to be installed on!
>
> *Note2:* Most of this information used to be on an Ubuntu wikipage called [RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows). While finding this page to link to in this post I noticed the page has had quite a change. The chrooting and stuff is not described anymore but instead a [boot-repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is available on some live cds. I have not experience with it, but I suppose it's worth a shot.

Comment: boot repair is indeed excellent. especially for unexperienced users.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Windows 7 boot environment is in control of the booting:
(Windows 7 MBR and Windows PBR + bootmgr + \Boot folder with BCD store on active partition)

1. Boot Ubuntu LiveCD and reinstall GRUB2 to **Partition boot record**.
2. Copy file /boot/grub/boot.img from Ubuntu to Windows 7 "\" root folder.
3. Reboot to Windows 7. Download and install [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net).
4. Create BootSector Loader. (rightclick select "Create BootSector Loader")
5. Amend drive and path of created loader to point to drive and path of "boot.img"

That's all.