# Grub cannot boot  after resizing windows XP (NTFS) partition. What is to be done?

Tags: 12.04, grub2, partitioning, lubuntu, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Repair Grub while dual booting ( win7 / ubuntu 11.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108375/how-to-repair-grub-while-dual-booting-win7-ubuntu-11-10)

I had installed Lubuntu on a PC with Windows XP and used dual boot for some time with no problems.

Since I had almost abandoned Windows (kept it for printing...) I decided to resize its ntfs partition and add the free space to my Ubuntu space.

Tried that with a `gparted` stick and a live cd but would not work due to an issue related to the ntfs partition: `gparted` signaled with a red exclamation point that there was a problem with that partition. I read that a checkdisk might solve it but in the end used EaseUS in Windows to shrink (resize) the ntfs partition and create a new one (`ext3`) from the space left.

All seemed ok with that procedure: but resizing the partition and moving the data might have affected the `grub` file: or whatever the following message means, which I get when trying to start my pc:

```
error: file not found
grub rescue>
```

Booting from a live cd I see, beside the shrinked windows partition and my old linux one, the newly created partition, containing a directory called `lost+found` that I cannot open.

Can I fix the grub file and recover both my XP and Lubuntu installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. Use the LiveCD for that. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) is one description on how to repair lost grub.

Another way of doing it is this:

1. Boot into LiveCD ("try out Ubuntu"). Open a terminal and type

   ```
   sudo -i
   ```

   Now you are root.
2. Mount the system already installed on the hard drive. We pretend that the hard drive of your computer is /dev/sda, and that your Ubuntu is installed on the partition /dev/sda3 (that is, /dev/sda3 would normally get mounted to /). You can find that out by typing `fdisk -l`.

   ```
   mkdir -p /mnt
   mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
   mount -t proc none /proc /mnt/proc
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
   ```
3. Now you will `chroot` into the system that is installed on your hard drive and run `update-grub` to restore your grub settings.

   ```
   chroot /mnt /bin/bash
   update-grub
   ```