# Cannot see boot options after editing grub background

Tags: boot, grub2, customization, desktop-background

After solving [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/186068/47206) I managed to get myself into truble again out of nothing by trying to change the display of the dual boot option page in [**Boot Customizer**](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/02/customize-ubuntu-grub-boot-menu-grub-customizer/).

I have changed **the background, the fonts size (I have increased them) and font style (I have chosen UnDotum**). But  Boot Customizer gave me an error (I mean a message that the application was closed unexpectedly or smth). I have restarted BootCustomizer and the settings were there.
When I rebooted, instead of the normal boot options list, **just the background image that I had selected and nothing else**.

I used  [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to repair grub, it says it did it successfully, but I still get the background image when I try to boot.

Any ideas?

(Could it be the matter  that I chose UnDotum font style? That was installed in Lubuntu - but how could it be accessible in displaying  boot options?)

The contents of `etc/default/grub` are:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

I have tried to modify `etc/default/grub`:
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 to 10
 GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true to false
and
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to ""

but it doesn't help

Also, using Shift doesn't make the list visible.

I am looking for something like a command that would **reset grub options to default**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The detailed instructions for resetting GRUB is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099). Read this carefully and proceed with caution.

The basic steps are as follows:

1. `chroot` as before and copy resolv.conf (may be needed to connect to the internet).

   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt && sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev && sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc && sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys && sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts && sudo chroot /mnt`

   `sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf`
2. Confirm Internet connection. Without it GRUB cannot be reinstalled
   and you will have a unbootable system.

   `sudo apt-get update`
3. Purge `grub`. **This will remove GRUB and the config files.**

   `sudo apt-get purge grub grub-pc grub-common`
4. Install GRUB again.

   `sudo apt-get install grub-common grub-pc`

   4. Reinstall the grub packages.

Here is what will happen:

- You will be given the opportunity to add extra kernel options to the
  kernel line. If you don't know, you probably don't need them ; <kbd>TAB</kbd> to highlight "<kbd>OK</kbd>" and press ENTER.
- Read the installation notes. <kbd>TAB</kbd> to "<kbd>OK</kbd>" to continue.
- When presented with the device option, use the UP/DN keys to select
  the correct drive (sdX).
- Make sure the installation drive `/dev/sdX` has an asterisk (*) (or a red spot like in the image below) next to  it. 
  If it doesn't, highlight it by <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> and press
  the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> to select it (= Just highlighting it with the up/down arrows is not enough to select it, you have to add that asterisk/dot - depending on the type of terminal - by pressing <kbd>Space Bar<kbd>.)</kbd></kbd>

[image]

- Do not select a partition ( example: [ ] /dev/sda5 , etc).
- TAB to "OK" and press ENTER. When it has finishing the
  installation, you should have Grub 2 installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i uninstalled and during install i am asked whre to install grub. butthe only options are:GRUB install devices:  [ ] /dev/sda (80026 MB; FUJITSU_MHT2080AH_PL) and     [ ] /dev/sdb (2004 MB; USB_DISK) - as an usb is connected. if i select ok it says: :You chose not to install GRUB to any devices etc" (im in live cd)

Comment: See expanded answer. You should choose /dev/sda.

Comment: is it ok that the only devices listed there were two: the cd rom and an usb drive?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the only devices were the CD rom and the USB drive. Are you sure the /dev/sda is the CD ROM? It is 80GB in size.

Comment: in fact is in MB. but upon retrying the procedure my drive appears: /dev/sda5 (56084 MB;

Comment: Select /dev/sda. **Not** /dev/sda5. GRUB should be installed in the MBR (Master Boot Record) of the disk drive and not inside any of the partitions of the disk.